# ShinyApp Image showed on windows but not on linux

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a problem with an image not showed in ubuntu and linux server but which appear on windows.
The image is included in a shiny app

The code is below :

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarUserPanel(name = "yo", 
                   subtitle = "ye"),
  # sidebarSearchForm(label = "Rechercher", "search", "searchButton"),
  sidebarMenu(
    tags$p(HTML('<img src="baba_logo.png" alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="230">'), 
           style = "font-size: 100%;"),
    menuItem("yo !!", tabName = "fpc", icon = icon("table")),
    menuItem("yee !!", tabName = "rrn", icon = icon("th")),
    br()
  )
);
```

Comment: instead of `tags$p(HTML(...))` , you can try using `img(src="baba_logo.png",height='200px',width='230px')` and placing image in `www/baba_logo.png`

Comment: Nice working fine on windows, I will try it tonignt on my linux desktop

Comment: I dont know why but when i remplaced ".png" by ".jpg" the problem was fixed ... thanks for help